# Change value after first onComplete event in React Component state / prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a logic to change the state value after the page is rendered and the `onComplete()` in `<CountdownCircleTimer>` is fired.

**Goal:**
The code has some other issues I am aware of, so please just focus on main question:

How to make logic with this behavior: after first `onComplete()` is fired, next firing (after `durationSeconds` is counted) should have different `timerVal` value. Any further timer `onComplete()` event is running with that value.

Scenario:
`timerVal` value, after browser is opened for 1st time, value is 33, seconds, but any proceeding onComplete() firing should have timerValue value of 60 (seconds).

**Here is my current code** (which obviously is not working):

```
import React , {useRef , useState } from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from 'react-countdown-circle-timer'

class Countdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            serverstate: 0,
            timerstate: 0
        }
        this.getServerTime = this.getServerTime.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getServerTime();
      this.setState(
        {serverstate: 60},
        () => {this.updateTimer()});
    }

    updateTimer() {
        const { timerstate, serverstate } = this.state;
        console.log("updateTimer 2 : Get "+this.state.serverstate+" / "+this.state.timerstate);
    }

    getServerTime() {
        fetch(`${this.props.sync}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((servertimeobj) => {
            this.setState({timerstate: servertimeobj.servertime},
              () => {this.updateTimer()});
            console.log("getServerTime: Get "+JSON.stringify(servertimeobj)+" Set "+this.state.timerstate);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Cannot retrieve seconds left to next minute in "+this.props.sync+" server");
            console.error(error);
          }
        );
    }

    render() {
        const fullVal = this.state.serverstate;
        //var now = new Date();
        //var secs = now.getSeconds();
        //var response = fullVal - secs;
        var timerVal = fullVal - this.state.timerstate;
        if (timerVal = fullVal) {
          timerVal = fullVal;
        }
        //console.log(response + "=" + fullVal + "-" + secs);
        console.log("Render: " + timerVal + "=" + fullVal + "-" + this.state.timerstate + "/" + this.state.serverstate);
        const authNav = this.state.user ?
        <div className="countdown-heading-username">
            <h1>Welcome, {this.state.user.name}!</h1>
        </div>:
            null;
        return (
            <div className="countdown-wrapper">
                <div className="countdown-item">
                <CountdownCircleTimer
                    isPlaying
                    onComplete={() => {
                        this.getServerTime(60);
                        if (this.props.betSlip[0] !== undefined) {
                            alert("Time is over!")
                            this.props.placeWin("win");
                        }
                        return [true, 1500]; // repeat animation in 1.5 seconds
                    }}
                    durationSeconds={timerVal}
                    initialRemainingTime={15}
                    colors={[['#A30000']]}
                />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**Assumption:**
My understanding was that it should work, if I update state in `componentDidMount()` with new value in `onComplete()` of the component, but it does not happen. I understand that using `setState()` in render is a no-no, but I do not know another ways to get the new value to `timerVal` applied.

**Question:**
What is proper way or preferably code change to make it happen?

Thank you for help as I m struggling for 3 days already to find elegant solution.

Comment: You do realize that `getServerTime`is an async function. 
You are not waiting for it complete in both the places i.e in `componentDidmount` and `onComplete` handler.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I did not realize getServerTime() is async. How/what is the way to make it wait for the completion?

Comment: use `async-await` or promises.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried it and seems like it does provide some improvement. I will experiment and maybe your comment would be considerable as actual Answer/Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to:

- implement async-await in getServerTime()
- perform setTimeout() with
  inclusive setState() with time, equivalent to the remaining seconds
  till next minute.